# Drupal gives me a blank page after moving from localhost to server

Tags: 7

I am new to Drupal . I moved my project from local host to server but it does not display either an database error or a page not found error.
Everything works better in local.
Please help me .

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Drupal Answers! What you're seeing is a White Screen of Death that can be caused by number of things because the server is hiding any errors. Please review [d.o.'s documentation](https://www.drupal.org/node/158043) on troubleshooting this problem.

Answer (score 1):

With the limited amount of details provided it is really hard to guess what might be causing it. So here are some things you may want to check:

- look in your webserver logs if any error is shown there.
- make sure you granted the appropriate file permissions.
- not enough PHP memory.

If you add more details to the question (like which OS, which webserver, etc) we might provide more answers also ...